# @PreDestroy and Spring AOP compatibility

Tags: java, spring, aop

I want to do some work on a graceful shutdown.
I've tried an approach shown below, but it doesn't work.
I've found a workaround (putting aspect annotation on @EventListener-marked method for ContextClosedEvent), but I want to understand, why it failed (`audit()` method not invoked at all without any exceptions).

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    
    @AuditProcess
    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

```
@Aspect
@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class AuditProcessAspect {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.aaa.bbb.annotation.AuditProcess) && execution(public * *(..))")
    public void executionOfPublicAuditableMethod() {
    }

    @Around("executionOfPublicAuditableMethod()")
    public Object audit(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        // some business logic ...
    }
}
```

As far as I digged into Spring 5 guts, I found that @PreDestroy is processed by CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor and @Aspect classes are transformed into Spring AOP Advisors by AspectJAdvisorFactory (CGLIB on JDK proxies, I guess). Thus, I don't understand, why aspect logic isn't called after sending SIGTERM to the application's JVM process. I even checked an output of `System.out.println(this.getClass().getCanonicalName())`, which was put into the body of the `destroy()` method - it looks like, for example, Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$25f99bf7. From my current point of view, there is nothing to prevent the aspect from wrapping around @PreDestroy callback method.
Nevertheless, it doesn't work.
Can somebody explain why?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the failure/what is not working ? Any exception ? What is expected from `audit()`method ? Is this method not triggered ?

Comment: @R.G The latter one. The `audit()` method contains some logging logic (writing to a security journal timestamps before and after calling a woven target method + the target method name, marked with @AuditProcess). After sending SIGTERM to the JVM process I don't see any records in the security journal, that looks like the method is not invoked. I had tried to add `System.out.println("aaabbb")` into the `audit()` body - there was no output in stdout terminal.

Comment: Is the `AuditProcess` annotation retention policy [RUNTIME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#RUNTIME) ?

Comment: @R.G Yes, retention policy RUNTIME and target - METHOD

Comment: Are you sure that `AuditProcessAspect` is even discovered by Spring's component scan? Did you mark aspect class with `@Component` (or similar) annotation?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Yes, I'm sure. As I wrote above, I found a workaround - make `@EventListener @AuditProcess public void onStop(ContextClosedEvent e) {}`. In that case audit logic is triggered, when SIGTERM is sent to the app's JVM process. I tend to think @kriegaex is right. Looks like CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor has a highest priority and stores a reference to a CGLIB proxy instance which is not wrapped by any aspect proxy yet. And some BPP with a lower priority decorate this reference with aspect proxies later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are my analysis. `main()` method modified to illustrate a bean method trigger.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplication(MainApp.class).run(args);
        MainApp app = context.getBean(MainApp.class);
        app.destroy();
    }


    @PreDestroy
    @AuditProcess
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("PreDestroy");
    }
}
```

When the `app.destory()` is called within `main()` method , the call is done on the proxy

```
MainApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f2c7a1b4(MainApp).destroy() line: 25    
MainApp$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8fbee297.invoke(int, Object, Object[]) line: not available 
MethodProxy.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 218  
... 
MyAspect.preDestroyLog(ProceedingJoinPoint) line: 27    
... 
CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Object, Method, Object[], MethodProxy) line: 692  
MainApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b98f9ed6.destroy() line: not available  
MainApp.main(String[]) line: 18
```

and when ApplicationContext shuts down , the lifecycle callback is done by the `InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeDestroyMethods(Object, String)`  on the actual object and not the proxy , hence no advise happens.

```
MainApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f2c7a1b4(MainApp).destroy() line: 25    
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 62  
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 566  
InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(Object) line: 389    
InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeDestroyMethods(Object, String) line: 347 
CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor).postProcessBeforeDestruction(Object, String) line: 177    
DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy() line: 242   
DefaultListableBeanFactory(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry).destroyBean(String, DisposableBean) line: 587  
DefaultListableBeanFactory(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry).destroySingleton(String) line: 559 
DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(String) line: 1152  
DefaultListableBeanFactory(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry).destroySingletons() line: 520  
DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons() line: 1145   
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).destroyBeans() line: 1111    
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).doClose() line: 1080 
AbstractApplicationContext$1.run() line: 996
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's clarifying all. As I suspected, CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor comes into play first and stores reference to a "raw" instance of a bean, which is not proxied yet.

Comment: Isn't that what I said in my answer? Even the example, creating a bean and calling it manually, is the same. There is some additional logging, which I did not bother to post when writing my own answer after analysing the problem locally, but basically it just confirms what I said before. I even pointed to javadoc explaining why this cannot be expected to be working in the first place. Besides, also in the canonical shutdown case the `destroy` method is called on the exact same CGLIB proxy as in the manual case. So that part of the explanation seems to be incorrect or at least unclear.

Comment: Inference that the lifecycle call back is on the actual bean method is based on the following difference  `MainApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f2c7a1b4(MainApp).destroy()` vs `MainApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b98f9ed6.destroy()` . The former is when the actual bean method is inovked. The reason for such an arrangment should be because of @kriegaex's answer and hence the reason for my upvote for the same.

Comment: Note: The "original" application object already is a proxy, albeit not an AOP proxy. You can run the application in debug mode and set a breakpoint in the `destroy()` method. There you can inspect both the original object (`this` from the breakpoint) and, when calling it as a bean method and clicking on the stack frame of the AOP proxy's `destroy()` method, the AOP proxy itself. You can evaluate code like `this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` and `this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()` in order to inspect the differences.

Comment: Then you will see that the original object has callbacks from `BeanMethodInterceptor` and `BeanFactoryAwareMethodInterceptor` only, while the AOP proxy has interceptors and dispatchers from `CglibAopProxy`. So when we speak of proxies in this context, we have to be precise and explain which of the two types we are talking about. The CGLIB proxy for the application instance is not an AOP proxy, which is why Spring AOP cannot work by design.

Comment: @kriegaex If you could update your answer with your findings , I can delete mine.

Comment: Not necessary, I think we have a good overview and background information now in the combination of our answers and comments. 

Answer (score 3):

If you would call the pre-destroy method manually like `appContext.getBean(Application.class).destroy()`, the aspect would be triggered. But in the part of the lifecycle where the application is being destroyed, no aspects seem to be applied anymore.

According to the [`@PreDestroy` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html), the annotated target method may be private and even final, i.e. two characteristics contradicting proxy-based Spring AOP usage. I am not a Spring or Java EE user at all and I might be wrong, but to me it looks as though this is not supposed to be working the way you expect it to. Spring experts around here like M. Deinum or R.G might be able to shed more light onto this issue.